# how to uninstall an recipe from AppCatlog Tab in Cloudify-V2.7 WebUI

Tags: recipe, cloudify

I have installed an recipe through Cloudify-V2.7  WebUI, how to uninstall that recipe from Cloudify-V2.7  WebUI.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have an `uninstall` option under `applications` tab.

[image]